# Uploading a file to a S3 bucket with a prefix using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am attempting to upload a file into a S3 bucket, but I don't have access to the root level of the bucket and I need to upload it to a certain prefix instead. The following code:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
open('/tmp/hello.txt', 'w+').write('Hello, world!')
s3_client.upload_file('/tmp/hello.txt', bucket_name, prefix+'hello-remote.txt')
```

Gives me an error:

`An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied: ClientError Traceback (most recent call last): File "/var/task/tracker.py", line 1009, in testHandler s3_client.upload_file('/tmp/hello.txt', bucket_name, prefix+'hello-remote.txt') File "/var/runtime/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 71, in upload_file extra_args=ExtraArgs, callback=Callback) File "/var/runtime/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 641, in upload_file self._put_object(filename, bucket, key, callback, extra_args) File "/var/runtime/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 651, in _put_object **extra_args) File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 228, in _api_call return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs) File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 492, in _make_api_call raise ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name) ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied`

`bucket_name` is in the format `abcd` while `prefix` is in the format `a/b/c/d/`. I'm not sure if the error is due to the slashes being wrong or if there's some way you can specify the prefix elsewhere, or if I don't have write permissions (although I supposedly do).

This code executes without any errors:

```
for object in output_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix):
    print(object.key)
```

Although there is no output as the bucket is empty.

Comment: `s3_client` is not defined.

Comment: I no longer have access to the code, but I would assume it was created using `s3_client = boto3.client('s3')` [taken from the docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#client)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turns out I needed SSE:

```
import boto3
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='YOUR_ACCESS_KEY', aws_secret_access_key='YOUR_SECRET')
transfer = S3Transfer(s3_client)
transfer.upload_file('/tmp/hello.txt', bucket_name, prefix+'hello-remote.txt', extra_args={'ServerSideEncryption': "AES256"})
```

Comment: What is `s3_client`? It is not defined anywhere. Neither is prefix.

Comment: @foxes - Thank you! I had completely forgot about the AES encryption, and was pulling my hair out wondering why it wasn't working!

Answer (score 47):

I'm assuming you have all this set up:

1. AWS Access Key ID and Secret Key set up (typically stored at `~/.aws/credentials`
2. You have access to S3 and you know your bucket names & prefixes (subdirectories)

According to the [Boto3 S3 `upload_file` documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file), you should upload your upload like this:

`upload_file(Filename, Bucket, Key, ExtraArgs=None, Callback=None, Config=None)`

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file('/tmp/hello.txt', 'mybucket', 'hello.txt')
```

The key to note here is `s3.meta.client`. Don't forget that.

Comment: I ran `s3_resource.meta.client.upload_file(PATH_IN_COMPUTER, BUCKET_NAME, KEY)` The code ran without errors but the file did not get uploaded. Any thoughts on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 22):

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file( 'csv1.csv', "bucketname", "prefixna/csv1.csv")
```

Comment: Seems the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37017853/6243352). Can you clarify what significant aspect is being added here? Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

Below is an alternative to John Adjei's answer. This is also taken from the [Boto3 S3 upload_file documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html). Because the Client is low-level (low abstraction / closer to machine code) it can improve performance - especially if you a dealing with Big Data.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
with open("FILE_NAME", "rb") as f:
    s3.upload_fileobj(f, "BUCKET_NAME", "OBJECT_NAME")
```

Comment:  I prefer the approach using `upload_fileobj()` as I am working with a filestream already vs. having access to the file path via the filesystem

Answer (score 9):

With `resource`

```py
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Bucket('BUCKET_NAME').upload_file('/tmp/hello.txt', '/detination/s3/path/hello.txt')
```

with `client`

```py
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.upload_file('/tmp/hello.txt', 'BUCKET_NAME', '/detination/s3/path/hello.txt')
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is my answer:

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client(service_name='s3', region_name='ap-southeast-1',
                         aws_access_key_id='AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
                         aws_secret_access_key='AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')

dest_bucket = 'data-lake'
dest_prefix = 'datamart/my_file_name/'

file_name = 'my_file_name'+ '.parquet'

s3.meta.client.delete_object(Bucket=dest_bucket,Key=dest_prefix + file_name)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @SvenEberth Thanks for your comment. I noted to help improve StackOverflow.